# Is the sum of the $n_{th}$ derivatives as $n \to \infty$, paired with each prime radical, unique to a function with certain characteristics?

Tags: functions

Let me know if my question deserves a hasty deleting. It deletion is warranted, I will do so with great speed and decisiveness.

First, we see that the $n_{th}$ derivatives (with the output of the function as well, 0th derivative) evaluated at 0 of certain functions converge to 0, such as for $cos(\frac{x}{4})$ and $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$. For those series of derivatives whose sum converges to a value less than $\infty$ (and greater than $-\infty$), do we have that this value is unique to the function? I suspect this is not true, but it leads to my next question:

Second, Take only the functions whose derivatives can all be divided by the same number such that only rational numbers are left. Taking the divided form, is it that the sum $\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}(f^{(n)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{p_i}})$, with $p_i$ is equal to the ith prime, uniquely determines a multiple of the function f from the set of functions whose derivatives are all a multiple of the same irrational or not irrational at all? If so, does $\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}(f^{(n)} \cdot \sqrt{p_i})$ also uniquely determine a multiple of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Your hopes for uniqueness are totally dashed by the fact that there exist nonzero *compactly supported smooth functions*. This means that there are functions which are nonzero, infinitely differentiable, and are zero outside of some interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Adding any one of these functions which vanish at $0$ with all derivatives also zero to any another smooth function $f$ will not change the value of $f$ or any of its derivatives at $0$. Since there are many such compactly supported smooth functions unfortunately this means that the properties you have described are very non-unique.

For example, consider $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{\frac{1}{1 - x^2}} & \lvert x \rvert < 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Good to know! Thanks! And do you know if it is possible to define a set of functions for which the derivative-radical sum does uniquely determine functions, in such a way that the set of functions is closed?